Difference between emplace_back and push_back in vector of std::regex
Why does v.emplace_back(nullptr); compile (and then results in a runtime error) but there is a compiler error for v.push_back(nullptr);?
Some articles recommend to use emplace_back over push_back in most cases, but emplace_back would cause potential bugs. When should I avoid using emplace_back?
#include <regex>
#include <vector>


int main() {
  std::vector<std::regex> v;

  v.emplace_back(nullptr);  // runtime error
  v.push_back(nullptr);     // compile error

  return 0;
}

gcc output:
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:9:14: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_regex<char> >::push_back(std::nullptr_t)'
    9 |   v.push_back(nullptr);     // compile error
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~


push_back allows only implicit conversions.  emplace_back allows explicit construction.

push_back(nullptr) fails at compile-time because push_back requires a reference (not a pointer, so not legally nullable) to an object of the type to be stored, or something implicitly convertible to said type. nullptr isn't a valid reference to std::regex, and won't implicitly convert to std::regex (the constructor, numbered (2) here, that would take a single pointer is marked explicit precisely to prevent this), so nothing of this type (a pointer type of any kind) will work under any circumstances, and this fails at compile-time.
It works with emplace_back because nullptr is of a legal type for constructing std::regex explicitly (constructor (2) accepts const CharT* s as the only argument, with defaulted flags). So v.emplace_back(nullptr); ends up trying to do roughly what v.push_back(std::regex(nullptr)); would do (but with guaranteed direct construction into the storage, no temporary that would be subsequently moved into the storage and then destructed); it's fully legal in the types involved, but std::regex(nullptr) is garbage and fails at runtime.
Syntactically, and per the signature of std::regex's constructor, what you tried to do was legal, it's just that a null pointer is a nonsensical argument in this case (the documentation requires a pointer to a null-terminated string, which nullptr isn't).
Basically, you need to know what you're storing to use emplace_back correctly. Violating the requirements of the stored item's constructor is what caused the problem here, not emplace_back itself. Avoiding emplace_back in general is not the way to go; in correct usage, it's optimally efficient (a single construction into the container, no temporaries at all), where push_back would add the (admittedly typically small) cost of creating, moving-from, and destroying a temporary.
